Вывод русских символов в Sublime Text 3 в консоль c++(gcc compiler)
Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с проблемой при выводе в консоль русских символов, перерыл множество источников, но точного ответа так и не нашел. Прошу ознакомится со скриншотом для понимания проблемы. В своем коде использую потоковый вывод русских символов.
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>  

using namespace std;

inline void russification() {
    std::system("chcp 1251");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
}
int main() {
    russification();
    // Задание №1
        
    cout << R"(
        У лукоморья дуб зелёный;
        Златая цепь на дубе том:
        И днём и ночью кот учёный
        Всё ходит по цепи кругом;
    )";

    // Задание №2
    int valueInCelsius{}; // Инициализируем 2 переменных для ввода и вывода значений
    int valueInFarengheit{};

    cout << "Введите значение в градусах Цельсия: ";
    cin >> valueInCelsius;
    valueInFarengheit *= (9/5) + 32; // переобразум значение переменной
    cout << endl << "Значение в градусах по Фаренгейту: " << valueInFarengheit;

    // Задание №3
    int a{}, b{}, c{}, d{}; // Инициализируем перемменые
    char dummychar{};

    cout << "Введите первую дробь: ";
    cin >> a >> dummychar >> b;
    cout << "Введите вторую дробь: ";
    cin >> c >> dummychar >> d;
    cout << "Сумма равна: " << (a*d + b*c) << '/' << (b*d);

}



Чтобы хак кодировкой 1251 сработал, сам код тоже должен быть сохранен в кодировке cp1251, у вас он скорее всего в какой-то другой кодировке, возможно в utf-8.

Т.к. это просто лаба, проще вообще забить на русский в консоли, и писать тупо транслитом или на английском.

Ты лучший, все заработало!!!! Поменял кодировку самого файла! Гений!

Чтобы не было вывода команды system замени текст chcp 1251 на chcp 1251 >nul
